# Is there a way to pass a parameter to Handlebars template in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I am using Meteor 0.5.2 and trying to solve what seems to me is an obvious pattern that should have an easy solution.

I have a template that should return different chunk of data in each of template instances.

For example - I have a template showing TV program - show by show.

Then I need to display two instances of the same template with different data - one with past shows and one with upcoming shows.

So I have a tv program template:

```
<template name="tv_program">
   {{#each shows}}
   ...
</template>
```

Ideally I would like do something like:

```
{{> tv_program past_shows}}
...
{{> tv_program upcoming_shows}}
```

to pass a parameter to tv_program template instance that I can read from JavaScript and adjust the mongo queries.

Currently I have copy/pasted my template/js code and adjusted the mongo queries but there has to be a better way.

I looked into partials/helpers with arguments but that doesn't seem to be the solution to my problem.

Thanks, Vladimir

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're approaching the problem at the wrong level. Rather than trying to tell your code what to do from your templates, you should tell your template what to do from your code. For instance:

```
Template.past_shows.shows = function() { return shows(-1); }

Template.upcoming_shows.shows = function() { return shows(1); }

function shows(order) {
  return Shows.find({}, {$sort: order});
}

<template name="past_shows">
  {{#each shows}}
    {{> show}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="upcoming_shows">
  {{#each shows}}
    {{> show}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="show">
  <li>{{_id}}: {{name}}</li>
</template>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in this direction Rahul. I refactored my code like you suggested. After it's done I am left with a chunk of HTML code that's identical in both of my templates (past_shows, upcoming_shows templates in the example - they should look the same and the real template code is complex with images and user related data). I guess this is ok as it's better to have redundant identical code in my views than in "controller/model" JavaScript.

Comment: Can you move the duplicate code into the `show` template instead?

Comment: Actually I can do that. My real code is different from simple example I used in my question. Thanks Dean.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a state machine for your app, such as [meteor-router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router), you can use one template and populate it with upcoming or past shows depending on app state.